# R filter data for Boxplot

Tags: r

I have red data from Excel into R and want to create a boxplot, but onyl with a subset of the data:

```
myData <- read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = "data_sheet")
boxplot(Tenants ~ Building, data = myData[Year == 2023])
```

"Tenants", "Building" and "Year" are all columns in the Excel file and also shown as variables in the data environment. Nevertheless, I do get the error:

> Error in eval(m$data, parent.frame()) : object 'Year' not found.

Do I have to transform the data somehow after reading it from Excel to use the filter like that?

Edit: If I remove the "filter" for year, the plot is working:

```
boxplot(Tenants ~ Building, data = myData)
```

Comment: i think you are missing `myData$..`: perhaps, `data = myData[myData$Year == "2023", ]` solves your issue? Please provide data as text, e.g. via `dput(myData)`.

Comment: See this link, the section "Selecting Observations":  https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html.  Specifically, notice that subsetting a data frame with `[]` expects 2 arguments to subset rows, separated by a comma.  it's `[rows-tochoose,columns-to-choose]`.  Without the comma it assumes you are trying to select variables not observations..

Answer (score -1):

I did find a very simple solution to my issue: Import the data as table. After that, the filtering is working as expected:

```
myData <- as.data.table(read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = "data_sheet"))
boxplot(Tenants ~ Building, data = myData[Year == 2023])
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: You got really good help for solving this in the first two comment to your opening post but switching to `data.table` is not the worst thing you could do.

Comment: I agree with Bernhard, though ... while I'm an avid and frequent user of `data.table`, I suggest that learning _its_ semantics and dialect while at the same time learning R itself may be confusing. The two are very different in many ways (e.g., `:=` vs `=`, referential vs copy-on-write, non-standard evaluation within `[`-expressions, just to name three big ones), and it is very easy to get confused. Your code works, TobiasBrenner, but be cautious with assuming you "understand" `data.table` by using this code here.